# Is there such thing as unflavoured wood chips or sawdust for smoking fish

Tags: fish, smoking

Is there any such thing as unflavoured sawdust

Comment: What do you mean by "unflavored" in this context?  All smoking procedures impart aroma/flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can usually find hickory, applewood, or other typical smoking wood chips in hardware stores around the barbecue section:

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/weber-hickory-2-lbs-wood-chips/1001046368

If by unflavoured you mean not hickory or applewood, you can make your own chips or dust and smoke with other hardwoods or fruit tree woods like oak and cherry. Oak supposedly is not as sweet and is more neutral tasting compared to fruit woods.

You will want to avoid pine woods and some soft woods as they contain resins and other compounds that will give off tastes.

Comment: Even oak has a distinctive flavour that goes beyond simple smokiness. And apple wood is often chosen for its flavour in smoking.